# What does Banshee need to recognize an audio book?

Tags: sound, banshee, mp3, playback, tag

I do have a few audio books, but Banshee doesn't recognize them.
What prerequisites have the files to meet to be recognized by Banshee as an audio book?

Is it a one or more mp3 tags or a special format?
I put all files in a seperate folder and set the location in Banshee correctly.

Please help if you can. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only way to currently add audiobooks to Banshee's audiobook library is to first import them into your Music library, then drag them to the Audiobook section.  Dragging them from other sources (such as playlists) [doesn't work yet](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608389), and [Banshee doesn't yet do anything special with a genre set to 'audiobook'](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631178).

Comment: I imported them successfully, but dragging the audiobooks to the appropriate section doesn't work. What now?

Comment: It works for me. I imported the book to the Music section first. Then I drag'n'droped it to the Audiobooks section and then I deleted it from the Music section. Thus a total of three operations. Banshee 2.6.2

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I imported the audio books into the main library and them located them by sorting my list by genre. Selecting all audio book files I dragged from the music library and dropped into audiobook section.

Items are still listed in music section. Not sure if it is safe to remove them or not...

Comment: This doesn't move the files to the audio book directory. The files remain in whatever directory is set up for music files.